# Como decrescer percentualmente em loop?

Tags: php

Preciso fazer um loop onde tenho um processo em que algo perde o peso a cada 1 minuto

Por exemplo:

```
100 - 20% = 80
80- 20% = 64
64 - 20% = 51.2
```

Assim vai até chegar em resultado que é 8.5899

```
$variavel100 - 20% = $total
$total - 20% = $total2
$total2 - 20% = $total3
```

assim vai, como fazer isso em um loop?

Comment: Você quer que o script aguarde 1 minuto? Ou pode seguir o loop direto?

Comment: preciso fazer um loop com uns dados (
a cada 1 dia uma pessoa  que tem 100kg perde 10% do seu peso
assim consequentemente até chegar no peso 47.82969kg) em quanto tempo a pessoa perdeu o peso ?

Comment: Mas por que 47.82969kg?

Comment: Importante dar uma lida em [ask] e [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) para poder elaborar melhor as próximas. Da forma como está, fala em loop (que aparentemente é um mero detalhe) e aparenta ser uma questão de aprender a fazer porcentagem (o que realmente não cabe no escopo). Alem disso, sabendo matemática, vai resolver a quantidade de tempo sem loop nenhum.

Comment: Escrevi um post há um tempo sobre uma solução para este exato problema. Você pode aplicar a fórmula de juro composto para isso. [Este é o link do meu post](https://fernandosavio.github.io/juros-compostos-em-um-exemplo-real) caso te ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser um while simples que checa o valor atual, algo como:

```
<?php

$peso = 100;
$porcentagem = 20;
$minimo = 8.58994;

while ($peso > $minimo) {
    echo "Atual: $peso\n";
    $peso -= (($peso / 100) * $porcentagem);
}

echo 'Resultado:' , $peso;
```

- Aqui é feito a regra de 3: `($peso / 100) * $porcentagem`
- O sinal `-=` indica decrescer o próprio valor da variável que será setada, que seria equivalente:

  ```
  $peso = $peso - (($peso / 100) * $porcentagem);
  ```

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/sNA8mu

---

Vale notar também que para se referir ao 20% você poderia usar um numero quebrado, por exemplo `0.80`, então se deseja decrescer o valor faça assim:

```
<?php

$peso = 100;
$porcentagem = .8; //o que deve sobrar e não o que subtrai
$minimo = 8.58994;

while ($peso > $minimo) {
    echo "Atual: $peso\n";
    $peso *= $porcentagem;
}

echo 'Resultado:' , $peso;
```

Note que `.80` é a praticamente mesma coisa que `0.80`, assim como `.8` também é praticamente que ambos. E mais importante é "80%", pois a porcentagem multiplicada irá resultar no valor que resta e não no valor que deseja diminuir.

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/U62596